# Django Haystack with Whoosh: Ignore characters when indexing/searching

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using haystack and whoosh to do provide search on my site, however, I need to index words that have square brackets or other characters in the middle of words ("fo[oba]r" for example) - is there a way to have either the index ignore these characters (and index as "foobar"), or allow for them when searching? Can I accomplish this with Whoosh, or would another backend be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you could implement this - basically what you want to do is strip the square brackets in your indexed content, and one way you could do this is to write a method on your model to return the modified content for the field you're indexing, and then use this in your search template.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would this entail creating a second field to store the stripped content, or just a method to access it? Is there a way to display the original content in the highlight after the search is performed?

Comment: No extra field, just a method you can access in your template. You can display the original text in your results page just by accessing the model, or storing the original in a field on your index. Not sure about highlighting sorry - I've never used it with haystack.